# SharePoint List items being used in an ASP Repeater

Tags: development, list, asp.net

If I am returning items from a SharePoint list is there anyway that I can store the values in an array or a list to use them in an ASP Repeater? I would have 4 values that would need to be stored (the List has 4 columns) and random numbers of records (rows) that would be returned. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("MYSITE"))
                    using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["SInfo"];
                        SPListItemCollection items = oList.Items;

                        foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
                        {
                            //ADD 4 Items to an array or List
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
Repeater.DataSource = oList.Items.GetDataTable();
Repeater.DataBind();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that but when I try to access my page I get an error `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Market'.` when I just used the line `Market: <%# Eval("Market") %> <br />` Why cant I reference my column market?

Comment: Did you inspect the table to see what columns it contains?  You may also want to use GetListItems with a query to only return the columns you want, especially if you have a lot of columns on the list and/or a lot of items.

Comment: I know it's been almost a year, but it helped me today! +1 from me. To display the desired column, I used the following: `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column-name") %>`

Comment: +1 from me, it helped me!

Answer (score 2):

I used this and working fine

```
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["FieldName"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use Eval("Market") because SPListItem does not have any property called Market.

what you can do is something like that:

```
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Market"] %>
```

You will just need to import the SharePoint assembly in your page :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>   
<%@ Assembly Name=""Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" %>
```

EDIT : it applies only if you had bind the SPListItemCollection directly without using the GetDataTable() method

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass entity object to your repeater exemple :

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

System.Collections.Generic.List<MyEntity> MyRepeaterBind(SPListItemCollection collection)
{
   List<MyEntity> items = new List<MyEntity>();
   foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
   {

      items.Add(new MyEntity
      {
         Title = Convert.ToString(item["your title column here"]),
         Description = Convert.ToString(item["your description column here"])
      });
   }
   YourRepeater.DataSource = items;
   YourRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

In your asp just use <%# Eval("Title") %> <%# Eval("Decription") %>